# Show by mathematical induction that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $(2n)!\lt 2^{2n}(n!)^{2}.$

Tags: solution-verification

I want a proof verification.

Prove that $$\boxed{ n\in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \Rightarrow (2n)!\lt 2^{2n}(n!)^{2}}$$ by mathematical induction.

Since $n=1$ implies that $(2\cdot 1)!=2\lt 2^{2\cdot 1}\cdot (1!)^2=2^{2}\cdot 1=4$ the base case holds.

Assume that $(2n)!\lt 2^{2n}(n!)^{2}$ is true for $n$. We now wish to show that this inequality is also true for $n+1$, namely that $$(2(n+1))!\lt 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^{2}.$$

Multiply the inequality $(2n)!\lt 2^{2n}(n!)^{2}$ by $(2(n+1))^{2}$ and we get that $$(2n)!\cdot (2(n+1))^{2}\lt 2^{2n}(n!)^{2}\cdot (2(n+1))^{2} \Leftrightarrow
\\
(2n)!\cdot (2(n+1))^{2}=(2(n+1))!\cdot 2(n+1)\lt 2^{2n}(n!)^{2}\cdot (2(n+1))^{2}=2^{2n}\cdot 2^{2}\cdot (n!\cdot (n+1))^{2}=2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^{2}.$$ That is $$(2(n+1))!\cdot 2(n+1)\lt 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^{2}.$$ Since $2(n+1)\gt 0$, $\forall n\geq 0$ we have that $$(2(n+1))!\lt (2(n+1))!\cdot 2(n+1)\lt 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^{2},$$ so $$(2(n+1))!\lt 2^{2(n+1)}((n+1)!)^{2}$$ which we wanted to show.

Comment: *(side comment: the inequality is obvious when you write $\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n\choose k}=2^{2n}$)*

Comment: There’s a very nice combinatorial proof as well.

Comment: You are on the right track, but there is a mistake on the LHS: $(2n)!(2(n+1))^2 \ne (2(n+1))!(2(n+1))$. Actually, $(2(n+1))!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!<(2n+2)(2n+2)(2n)!=(2n)!(2(n+1))^2$.

Comment: Oh! I see my mistake. Thank you! But, with that correction the proof is complete, right?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Another proof :**

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\binom{2n}{n}< \sum\limits_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} = 2^{2n}$$